# GitLab-CE installation using Docker-Compose file - Ssh git user asking password

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ce

I have successfully installed GitLab-CE edition using `Docker-Compose file` as per below link on my Docker host server.

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` content as follows.

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2223
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
    - '2223:22'
  volumes:
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '$GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

In one of my Ubuntu client system when I run `ssh -T -p 2223 git@gitlab.example.com` it works (It shows `Welcome to GitLab`). Whereas in my docker host if I remove the following - `gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2223` in my `gitlab.rb` file after running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. Again if i run `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com` it is asking `git` user's password.

Docker-Server's 22 port listening as below.

```
netstat -tulnp | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1516/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      2587/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1516/sshd
```

Since `sshd` service is already running on `22` port on my docker server, So is there any way to use 22 default port to clone our GitLab repository? Without changing sshd default port. Like below example command i would want to clone. So any suggestion would be helpful.

```
git clone git@gitlab.example.com:sample-group/sample.git
```

@Exadra37, i have updated the data you shared and tried to rebuild, but it fails.

```
[root@gitlab]# docker-compose up --build
WARNING: The SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Recreating 486bb3cb8496_docker-gitlab-ce_web_1 ... error

ERROR: for 486bb3cb8496_docker-gitlab-ce_web_1  Cannot create container for service web: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your ssh socket into the container.

Add the following to your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
environment:
  - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
volumes:
  - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
```

Comment: @ Exadra37, Thanks for the reply. i have updated the question.

Comment: Oh I forgot this works in my laptop because the OS in a desktop normally has an ssh agent installed, but not on server OS. In this case you may want to try to mount the `~/.ssh` folder to the same location in the container, so that git inside the container can use your ssh keys to access Gitlab repos via SSH.

Comment: '.ssh' folder of my docket host need to be mounted in the container.For this I need to update the 'docker-compose.yml' volume:  section correct?

Comment: yes... try to add to the volumes section `/home/host-user/.ssh:/home/container-user/.ssh`

Comment: i have added `/root/.ssh:/root/.ssh/` under `volumes:` section and i have removed `- SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent` from `environment` But still `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com` asking password. `environment` is must?

Comment: You mean, asking the passphrase for your private key `id_rsa`?

Comment: Git user password it is asking.

Comment: Reading again your question and I think I misunderstood it in the first time. Just leave Gitlab inside the container configured fo ssh port `2223` and in your docker-compose.yml file swap your port mapping to `- 22:2223`.

Comment: Swapped the port, But rebuild fails with following error. `ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker-gitlab-ce_web_1 (056f755baedbd11613fc515b71153257ad37053edae9e0859090db6581ecb657): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:22: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that port 22 was already in use in your host.